# Creating UnfoldingMap instance with java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: quality error

Tags: java, processing

I try to create PApplet (Processing) with UnfoldingMap (v0.9.6). Unfortunatelly I get **java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: quality** error at this line:  map = new UnfoldingMap(this, p1). What may be the reason if it?

```
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.UnfoldingMap;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.AbstractMapProvider;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.Google;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.utils.MapUtils;
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class MyPApplet2 extends PApplet{

    UnfoldingMap map;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.main(new String[] {MyPApplet2.class.getName() });
    }

    public void settings() {
        size(400, 400, P2D);
    }

    public void setup() {
        AbstractMapProvider p1 = new Google.GoogleTerrainProvider();
        map = new UnfoldingMap(this, p1);
        MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map);       
    }

    public void draw() {        
        map.draw();
    }   
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: quality
    at processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL$2.run(PSurfaceJOGL.java:443)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: quality
    at de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.mapdisplay.OpenGLMapDisplay.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.mapdisplay.MapDisplayFactory.getMapDisplay(Unknown Source)
    at de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.UnfoldingMap.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.UnfoldingMap.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at module3.MyPApplet2.setup(MyPApplet2.java:23)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2374)
    at processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL$DrawListener.display(PSurfaceJOGL.java:731)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:692)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:674)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawableBase$2.run(GLAutoDrawableBase.java:443)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1293)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:1147)
    at com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow.display(GLWindow.java:759)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AWTAnimatorImpl.display(AWTAnimatorImpl.java:81)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AnimatorBase.display(AnimatorBase.java:452)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator$MainTask.run(FPSAnimator.java:178)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown because we changed the definition of a specific class and we didn’t re-compile those classes that have a reference to that class.

```
 /**
 * Creates a new full canvas map with the given ID.
 * 
 * @param p
 *            The main applet.
 * @param id
 *            The ID of this map.
 */
public UnfoldingMap(PApplet p, String id) {
    this(p, id, 0, 0, p.width, p.height, true, false, null, null);
}
```

Try to use something like this:

```
    AbstractMapProvider p1 = new Google.GoogleTerrainProvider(); 
    settings();
    map = new UnfoldingMap(this, 50, 50, 500, 350, p1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. How can I get rid with this?

Comment: Well it works if I use size(800, 600) instead of size(800, 600, P2D). The downside of this solution is that the map is not sticked to its position in the PApplet window and it may exceed given size.