# Bug with Eclipse + Processing 3.2.1 + UnfoldingMaps

Tags: eclipse, processing

I downloaded latest JOGL, Processing 3.2.1 and trying to compile this code:

```java
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.UnfoldingMap;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.geo.Location;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.AbstractMapProvider;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.Google;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.MBTilesMapProvider;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.Microsoft;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.OpenStreetMap;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.Yahoo;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.utils.MapUtils;
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class TwoMaps extends PApplet {

public UnfoldingMap map1;
public UnfoldingMap map2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PApplet.main("TwoMaps");


}

public void settings() {

    size(800, 600, P2D);

}



public void setup() {

    String mbTilesString = "blankLight-1-3.mbtiles";

    final boolean offline = false;

    this.background(200, 200, 200);

    AbstractMapProvider provider = new Microsoft.RoadProvider(); 
    int zoomLevel = 10;

    if (offline) {
        provider = new MBTilesMapProvider(mbTilesString);
        zoomLevel = 3;
    }

    map1 = new UnfoldingMap(this, 50, 50, 350, 500, provider);
    map2 = new UnfoldingMap(this, 425, 50, 350, 500, provider);

    map1.zoomAndPanTo(zoomLevel, new Location(32.9f, -117.2f));
    map2.zoomAndPanTo(zoomLevel, new Location(55.45f, 40f));

    MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map1);
    MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map2);

}

public void draw() {
    map1.draw();
    map2.draw();
}

}
```

And then I get this message in console and couldn't find anythig in internet:

```java
Unfolding Map v0.9.6
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: quality
at processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL$2.run(PSurfaceJOGL.java:461)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: quality
at de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.mapdisplay.OpenGLMapDisplay.<init>(Unknown Source)
at de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.mapdisplay.MapDisplayFactory.getMapDisplay(Unknown Source)
at de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.UnfoldingMap.<init>(Unknown Source)
at de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.UnfoldingMap.<init>(Unknown Source)
at TwoMaps.setup(TwoMaps.java:47)
at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2387)
at processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL$DrawListener.display(PSurfaceJOGL.java:871)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:692)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:674)
at jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawableBase$2.run(GLAutoDrawableBase.java:443)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1293)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:1147)
at com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow.display(GLWindow.java:759)
at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AWTAnimatorImpl.display(AWTAnimatorImpl.java:81)
at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AnimatorBase.display(AnimatorBase.java:452)
at com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator$MainTask.run(FPSAnimator.java:178)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

But if I don't use rendering `P2D` inside the `size()` method then it works, but works bad and slow and shows only one map.

But the most funny thing is that if I use Processing 2.2.1 where the base class for scetch is java.Applet then code works even with `P2D` inside `size()` method.

AMD Mobility Radeon HD 5000 Drivers are the latest.

Comment: As Kevin Workman said you need to either use Processing 2, or send us an e-mail to get a beta of Unfolding Maps for Processing 3.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I will wait when Unfolding maps will be done for Processing 3. Do you know when it could be possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Unfolding Maps is not compatible with Processing 3. For now you're going to have to stick with Processing 2.

If you really, really, really need to use Processing 3, you could try the answer here: [Creating UnfoldingMap instance with java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: quality error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442336/creating-unfoldingmap-instance-with-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-quality-error)

But you're probably best off just going back to Processing 2.

Another note: you shouldn't download JOGL at all. Processing comes with the version of JOGL that it needs. You should be using that version of JOGL, not a newer version you download separately.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't even think about uncompatibility of UnfoldingMaps 0.9.6 and Processing 3.2.1.

But I am interesting now, where can I use such project with map, that use java Applets. I thought applets are dead and Newest broswers just don't support applets anymore. 
So where I can use such project?

Thank you very much.

Comment: @Turtality I'm not really sure what you're asking. Yes applets are pretty much dead. You can only really use them in environments where you can guarantee a specific browser and Java version (which is hard to do on computers you don't have control over). But you don't have to deploy as an applet. You could deploy as a runnable jar, or an executable, or you could try to use web start.

Comment: If I understood your correctly @Turtality and you want to use interactive maps in a browser environment you simply can use any of the other non-Java mapping libraries, e.g. Leaflet.

Unfolding is not intended for browsers (even though it works if you are ok with applets), and follows Processing's approach to use it for a) learning, b) experiments/prototypes/research, and c) installations/exhibitions/other environments, you have complete control over.

Comment: @tnagel The problem is that these maps aren't incorporated into Processing whereas Unfolding Maps is. In other words, you can't (easily) write Processing sketches that interact with any existing JavaScript map libraries.